# Image not able to load when using p5js outside of online editor

Tags: p5.js

I am using p5js and I am trying to load and display some images in my directory. I am trying to use the `loadImage()` method in my preload function to load an image. However, when I run the program, I get these errors

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///Users/mainuser/Documents/school/Senior/FinalProject/imgs/arms_up.png. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
```

```
 p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path (imgs/arms_up.png) is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server. (More info at https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)
```

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at fetch (p5.js:28096)
    at p5._main.default.loadImage (p5.js:80673)
    at p5.js:62949
    at preload (script.js:118)
    at p5._start (p5.js:62905)
    at new p5 (p5.js:63261)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:62189)
```

My `imgs` folder is within the same folder as my `index.html`

My guess is that `fetch()` might need an actual URL instead of a file path.

Anybody else run into this problem? I've attached my code below (i took out irrelevant code). Thank you!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/pose@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-pose.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Pose Game</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="init()">Start Game!</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="restart_game()">Restart Game</button>
        <div id="main-div">
            <div id="flex-div">
                <div id="webcam-div">
                    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="p5-div"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

script.js

```
let arms_up_png;
let left_arm_up;
let right_arm_up;

function preload() {
   arms_up_png = loadImage("imgs/arms_up.png");
}


function setup() {
    var canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
    canvas.parent('p5-div');
}

function draw() {
    background('green');
    image(arms_up_png, 50, 50, 20, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `fetch()` will not work with local file paths, and because p5js needs to load the contents of the image file in order to display it you also cannot use local file paths with the p5js `loadImage()` function. In order to run your sketch locally you will need to use a local web server. The [Visual Studio Code Live Server extension](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server) is quite handy for this purpose.